# Hide query running time from chunk output in knitr

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, r-markdown

How can I hide the running time from chunk outputs??  thanks!!

Running query:   RUNNING  2.1s
Running query:   RUNNING  2.6s
Running query:   RUNNING  3.2s
Running query:   RUNNING  3.8s
Running query:   RUNNING  4.4s
Running query:   RUNNING  5.0s
Running query:   RUNNING  5.6s
Running query:   RUNNING  6.5s
Running query:   RUNNING  7.1s
Running query:   RUNNING  7.7s

Comment: Which package are you running that's giving you those messages? Have you tried adding message=FALSE to your chunk?

Answer (score 1):

Use chunk options

- message = FALSE
- warning = FALSE
- error = FALSE